# Are there good ways of relating a minor to the full determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-graph-theory, determinants, graph-minors

Say $A$ is a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix and we augment it by a $n^{th}$ row and a column and get a $n \times n$ matrix $B$. Is there a nice way to relate $det(B)$ and $det(A)$ and the added row and column?

---

A close by thing I am reminded of is this,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: Well, $\text{det}(B)$ is a sum of $n$ terms and only one of them is a multiple of $\text{det}(A)$. So you can't expect much here without severely constraining that additional row and column, can you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, there is the Sherman-Morrison formula
$$\det B=(\det A)(b-yA^{-1}x),$$
where $b, x$ and $y$ are blocks:
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} A & x \\ y & b \end{pmatrix}.$$

*Edit*. After Hachino's comment, one can also write
$$\det B=b\det A-y\hat Ax,$$
where $\hat A$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix.

Comment: This only works for $\det(A) \neq 0$...

Comment: @Michael: of course

Comment: Not only, if one recalls that $det(A) A^{-1}$ is the adjunct matrix of $A$ (nothing to do with adjoints or symmetric matrices here), which is defined for any matrix.

Comment: @Hachino. Right !

Comment: The formula (with the cofactor matrix) for $\det B$ is equation $(19)$ in Cauchy's 1815 memoir on determinants.

Comment: @DenisSerre Thanks for the this! This is not the standard Sherman-Morrison. Can you kindly link to some resource which gives a proof and an explanation and some context of it?

Comment: @user6818. The Sherman-Morrison formula applies more generally when $A$ is a diagonal block of $B$, of any size. The (easy) proof consists in factorizing $B=LU$ blockwise. Here $L$ is lower blockwise triangular with diagonal blocks being identity matrices, and $U$ is upper blockwise triangular.